# Laravel how to access Auth in javascript file.

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

In my `@yield('scripts')` section have a javascript call where I only show a button if the user is an admin.

I want to put the javascript in my library because it gets used more than once. However Blade/php doesn't work when I try to include this section in a library `myApp.js`

**javascript section**

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
   title: 'Age Not Met',
 message: 'The attendee does not meet the age reguirement for this program.',
    type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING,
 buttons: [
          @if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')||Auth::user()->hasRole('programmer'))
          {
              label: 'OVERIDE',
           cssClass: 'btn-danger',
             action: function(dialogItself){
                     checkbox.prop('checked', true);
//...rest irrelevant
```

I tried to use a variable in my layout to replace the blade/php call but the variable is blank. Also I realized I can't just replace the blade with an `if(isAdmin)` because it's in a function parameter...How do I do get the button to appear only for the admin?.

**in layout**

```
<script>
var isAdmin = {{ (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')||Auth::user()->hasRole('programmer')) }}
</script>
```

Comment: If you plan to let javascript decide if the button is showed or not, you can let the button be visible all the time as your user will be able to show it either way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You approach of using `if(isAdmin)` is correct. You should define that as you have done in your view and then:

```
var varButtons = []
if(isAdmin){
          varButtons = [{
              label: 'OVERIDE',
           cssClass: 'btn-danger',
             action: function(dialogItself){
                     checkbox.prop('checked', true);   
                    }
                }]; 
}
BootstrapDialog.show({
       title: 'Age Not Met',
     message: 'The attendee does not meet the age reguirement for this program.',
        type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING,
     buttons: varButtons
```